# session expires in codeigniter when ajax call is present (CI version 3.0.3)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I am using the latest version of codeigniter.
The problem is session is expired automatically after sometime (some ajax calls present in the page)

I've found one solution for this problem that says replace my `session.php`
with [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php)

but it didn't worked for me.
My codeigniter version is 3.0.3

**UPDATE**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: PLease show your config session options (application/config/config.php, sess_*).

Comment: How it even works with `sess_save_path === NULL`? Read from comments in config.php: `IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!` — https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php